# When editting a Rails project with Vim, the SnipMate plugin only loads the ruby snippets. How can I get the ruby-rails snippets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, snipmate

When editing my Rails app, snipMate only seems to load the ruby snippets file and not the ruby-rails snippets file as the ruby snippets work and the rails snippets do not. I am using them within a Rails application.

Any idea what the problem may be?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wild guess: ruby snippets are loaded for .rb extensions but rails snippets are not.

Do you use [this version of SnipMate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate)? If so there seems to be [a possibility](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/blob/master/autoload/snipMate.vim#L13) to use extra snippets for a given filetype.

If you use the original, like me, I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: This looks like a decent lead to play around with. Thank you.